# Ofbiz : Diffrence between item ATP, item QOH and product ATP , product QOH

Tags: java, ofbiz

I would really appreciate if some one could tell me the difference between **(item ATP, item QOH ) and (product ATP , product QOH) in ofbiz** . I have googled it but could not find much details . We were previously using drop shipment but have shifted to inventory . We are facing some issue because of this but lack of documentation is holding us back . We would really appriciate if you could provide a small example or a link .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ATP -- > Available To Promise
QOH -- > Quantity On Hand

In InventoryItem, ATP is the inventory that is available to promise. For example

You start with Inventory = 100
At 10:00AM take order for 10 item
Now, ATP = 90 (you have already promised 10 to someone by taking an order) 
But still your QOH = 100

Let us say at 11:00AM you dispatch/ship the order taken at 10:00 AM.
now, your 
ATP = 90 and 
QOH = 90

Answer (score 0):

QOH refers to the count of goods, physically present at that moment in the warehouse.
ATP takes into account, the restocking quantity and the orders promised for delivery.

For example: Let's suppose that I have 100 goods in the warehouse at 10 AM, and I will get a new stock of 50 goods today and also need to deliver 30 units to the customers today at 6 PM.

Here,my QOH will be 100 till 6 PM, but will decrease to 70(100-customer order of 30 units) after 6 PM.
Whereas my ATP for today will be: 100+50(restocking)-30(customer orders)=120